# Can anyone identify this plant/weed in Northern Indiana

Tags: identification, weeds

This one here is about 4-5 feet tall they are about 1/8" to 1/4" from top to bottom in  Northern Indiana[image]

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Comment: Northern Indiana

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a gall produced by a fly on a species of goldenrod. When the fly lays the eggs in the tip of the plant a hormone is produced that interferes with the normal development of the plant cells, forming that bulge which will protect the developing eggs and larvae. See for example [this discussion](https://wimastergardener.org/article/goldenrod-gall-fly-eurosta-solidagnis/).